# Django: Passing url slugs to formset queryset

Tags: django, formset

I am trying to [change the queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset) of my formset with this 'alternative approach':

> Alternatively, you can create a subclass that sets self.queryset in
>   **init**:

```
from django.forms import BaseModelFormSet from myapp.models import Author

class BaseAuthorFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.queryset = Author.objects.filter(name__startswith='O')
```

Now my problem is, that I have to pass variables into this queryset. Therefore I tried to adjust BaseAuthorFormSet in my forms.py like that:

```
class BaseAssignAttendeeFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):

    def __init__(self, order_reference, access_key, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.queryset = Attendee.objects.filter(
            order__order_reference=order_reference,
            order__access_key=access_key,
        )
```

My `function-based-view` in `views.py` starts like that: `def assign_attendee(request, order_reference, access_key):` `order_reference` and `access_key` are slugs that come from the url.

Anyone knows the way to pass these two to my queryset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass arguments during formset initializing in the view:

```
MyFormSet = modelformset_factory(MyModel, fields=('name', 'title'), formset=BaseAssignAttendeeFormSet)
formset = MyFormSet(order_reference, access_key, #Other orguments here)
```

In formset you need to call superclass's `__init__` method:

```
class BaseAssignAttendeeFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):

    def __init__(self, order_reference, access_key, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.queryset = Attendee.objects.filter(
            order__order_reference=order_reference,
            order__access_key=access_key,
        )
```